# How to use regular expression to search value field of child object with match_phrase query in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

The documents for hierarchy in Elasticseach as follows

```
"hierarchy":{
        "username":"Nothing on",
        "Location":"",
        "Owner":"unknown",
        "works": "IT"
        
    }
```

Is there any method to search value with any field inside the hierarchy, fields within the hierarchy is dynamic and tried to use regular expression pattern matching and getting error.

**we cant specify like hierarchy.works, hierarchy.Owner** etc.. as **fields inside hierarchy is dynamic** and also used escape string but it also gives an error.

```
{
        "from": 0,
        "query": {
            "multi_match": {
                "query": "IT",
                "type": "phrase_prefix",
                "fields": [
                    "number",
                    "name",
                    "address",
                    "hierarchy.*.",
                    "tags"
                ],
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> If no fields are provided, the multi_match query defaults to the
> index.query.default_field index settings, which in turn defaults to *.
> This extracts all fields in the mapping that are eligible to term queries and filters the metadata fields. All extracted fields are then
> combined to build a query.

Since the `hierarchy` field is dynamic so you cannot specify the field that is to be queried, so one way to query your query can be to add no fields in the `field` parameter.

**Index Data 1:**

```
{
  "hierarchy": {
    "username": "Nothing on",
    "Location": "",
    "Owner": "unknown",
    "works": "IT",
    "education":"btech"
  }
}
```

**Index Data 2:**

```
{
  "hierarchy": {
    "username": "Nothing on",
    "Location": "",
    "Owner": "unknown",
    "works": "IT"
  }
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "btech",
      "type": "phrase_prefix"
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
 "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "64467424",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.2876821,
        "_source": {
          "hierarchy": {
            "username": "Nothing on",
            "Location": "",
            "Owner": "unknown",
            "works": "IT",
            "education": "btech"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
```

**Edit 1:**

> You can use the query_string query to create a complex search that
> includes wildcard characters, searches across multiple fields, and
> more. While versatile, the query is strict and returns an error if the
> query string includes any invalid syntax.

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "fields": [
        "number",
        "name",
        "address",
        "hierarchy*",
        "tags"
      ],
      "query": "btech"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: 1] Wanted to search based on only particular fields, in the multi-match query it will search for all fields in the document to match with the result.
2]  In query_string if we add any filed like mac address and query that you will get an exception like - Failed to parse the query